# How to configure server (ldap?) for email?

Tags: email, server, thunderbird

I want to be able to read my email on several devices, preferably with Thunderbird. The process of reading it removes it from the server, downloading it onto whatever device I'm using. I would like to be able to have my email downloaded to my private server and be able to access it from any of my devices, preferably with "new mail" notifications being available on whatever device reads it first.

I thought I might be able to store it with LDAP, but I think that applies to only the address books.

Can someone outline what I would need to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: This is off-topic here, but with more detail could be a good fit for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com). LDAP is for authentication, IMAP/SMTP are for email.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your accounts configured as POP3 with activated deletion when downloading. The most common way is to use IMAP instead (although it is also possible to configure POP3 to not delete e-mails on the server). Most clients will not delete e-mails from the server then by default. Please see your provider's instructions fot the correct IMAP settings.

For Thunderbird, see http://mzl.la/1ApHlPG on how to migrate to IMAP and http://mzl.la/1ApHiDr for more information on IMAP.

LDAP is not directly related to your e-mails.